# JBoss 7 - retrieve path from system property in standalone.xml

Tags: ssl, jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure ssl in standalone.xml and pass value of path for keystore file by system property.

My first try was to define path which value will be the property:

```
<paths>
    <path name="ssl.dir" path="${ssl.dir.property}"/>
</paths>
```

And consequently use it in ssl configuration:

```
<server-identities>
    <ssl>
        <keystore path="server/server.keystore" relative-to="ssl.dir" keystore-password="xxxxxx"/>
    </ssl>
</server-identities>
```

But the system property "ssl.dir.property" is not resolved in this case. The value of "ssl.dir" is empty.
If the value of system property is put directly into keystore path without definition of "relative-to", it also doesn't work.

Do you know any way how to pass a path value into standalone.xml which could be used as keystore path?

I couldn't find anything on the web so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of JBoss AS? This doesn't work in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final and lower.

Comment: It doesn't work in 7.1.1.Final. In lower versions I haven't checked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the path attribute didn't allow expressions until after 7.1.1.Final was released. You can use [EAP 6.1.Alpha](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) which is essentially 7.2.0.Final. It's built off that tag